# Reference to another item inside a ListView with ViewHolder

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-viewholder

I need a little bit of help: I have a listview with a custom list item and a viewholder. The code I copied represents the adapter I am using but a simplier version. For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have an `ImageView` and a `LinearLayout` inside every single `ListView` item. I would like to apply a `setOnClickListener` on every item which should do the following: change the visibility of the LinearLayout inside ANOTHER item, so in another position (e.g. always the 5th). Obviously if i call `holder.rl.setvisibility(..)`, it changes the visibility in the same position. I assume I can somehow reference to the item I need to change but I am not sure. How could you guys do this?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context mContext) {
       this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bImageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.discover_item_layout_my, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            assert view != null;

            holder.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_discover_listitem_itemimage);
            holder.ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.anim_rl);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.itemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //need to set holder.ll visibility to GONE but in another position
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView itemImage;
            LinearLayout ll;
        }
    }
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: just u  a array of true/false in adapaetr constacrter and when u click updated adapter

Comment: Its ok, but how can I change the e.g 5th item's layout?

Comment: if(position==5){} than do somethink

Comment: Start with removing the onClickListener. Instead set (outside the adapter) an OnItemClickListener on the listView.

Comment: I have several other buttons inside every listview item and I need to have defined their onClickListeners inside the Adapter.

Comment: Ok. Can you determine the 'position' in OnClick? And tell a little bit more about which 'other position' should be handled.

Comment: the setOnItemClickListener can determine the position, but I use a much more complicated customized layout with several buttons inside. The only thing I need to do is change the layout (holder.ll) visibility in another position (e.g. 5th) if I click on an item inside the layout (itemImage) in ANY position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attached some code detailing what to do. It's off the top of my head so may need a little tweaking in order to compile.  Hopefully it'll get the point across.

Just create a global field which tracks the state of the 5th position's visibility.

```
private int mFifthVisibility = View.VISIBLE;  //Starting value.
```

Then in the `onClickListener` just toggle that variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
holder.itemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mFifthVisibility = View.GONE;  //Or Invisible
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Finally, in the `getView()` method, update your view's visibility like so:

```
 holder.ll.setVisibility((position == 5) ? mFifthVisibility : View.VISIBLE);
```

Side note, unless you are specifically doing it for a reason, your `getItem()` method should be returning a value.  Not null. That'll def confuse any other programmer using your code.

Comment: Shame on me. Nice one! I did put the notifyDataSetChanged somewhere wrong place.. Thank you Jay Soyer!

Comment: One more thing: notifyDataSetChanged refreshes the whole listview, I have images from database to be loaded. How can I tell that ONLY that 5th item should be refreshed? (so the other ones dont get refreshed)

Comment: You can't...easily. The work around would be to track and store every generated view by position in some sort of WeakReferenced map. It's tricky and you'll find various edge case where it'll fail. Besides, that idea goes against how Adapters are designed and meant to be used.  `NotifyDataSetChange`, will only refresh the visible positions...not all positions.  Try instead to cache your images. Where by you first attempt to pull cache, then you pull from DB.